# Using xbuild on iOS application does not generate ipa

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have implemented Continuous Integration with Jenkins to help perform our builds for faster deployment. We have reviewed the documentation provided through the [Xamarin website](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/), and have come to an issue. In the walkthrough it describes how to use various plugins to perform the process, we use build scripts to perform our builds because we have some post-actions that we execute after the build, such as submitting the ipa to the TestFlight. The problem is that for iOS it is has been [documented](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/build-system/#Common_command_line_actions) that we need to use xbuild instead of mdtool when building from the terminal/command line.

We followed this [portion of the guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/#Compiling_a_Xamarin.iOS_Applications) to construct our xbuild within the build script. It appears that the xbuild command works and creates the project reference dlls and even generates an exe, but does not generate an ipa file even if we set this `/p:BuildIpa=true` on the xbuild to ensure the ipa generation. We also have provided a location for the ipa to be generated within to ensure we are not missing the file with this `/p:IpaPackageDir=$BUILD_PATH`. Here is the whole xbuild command that we are currently using, is there something that is incorrect or we are missing?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild $PROJECT_FILE / t:Build /p:BuildIpa=true /p:IpaPackageDir=$BUILD_PATH /p:Configuration=”Release” /p:Platform=”iPhone” /p:OutputPath=$BUILD_PATH
```

(`$BUILD_PATH`)      --  The build path is just “%WORKSPACE%\bin\iPhone\Release\”

I did find [this resource](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/teamcity/#Compiling_a_Xamarin.Android_Application) as well, which states that xbuild requires the solution file for iOS to build correctly, is that correct?

If this is correct, how do we resolve these errors because I have not been able to find any documentation that explains how to properly define the solution and project files for xbuild deployment, or even how to exclude particular projects during the build:

```
/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.Forms.UWP/Mobile3.Forms.UWP.csproj:  warning : Could not find project file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v14.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets, to import. Ignoring.
/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.ServicePro.UWP/Mobile3.ServicePro.UWP.csproj:  warning : Could not find project file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v14.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets, to import. Ignoring.
Project "/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.sln" (Mobile3.ServicePro.iOS target(s)):
        Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.sln: error : Invalid solution configuration and platform: "“Release”|“iPhone”".
        Task "Error" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in project "/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/Users/developer/.jenkins/workspace/Mobile3_Branch_3.20/ServicePro/iOS/Mobile3.sln".-- FAILED
```

Here is the xbuild command we used to build the solution:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild /p:Configuration=”Release” /p:Platform=”iPhone” /p:OutputPath=$BUILD_PATH /p:BuildIpa=true /p:IpaPackageDir=$BUILD_PATH /t:Build $SOLUTION_FILE
```

We are not concerned with building the UWP projects when building the iOS project because we have a separate build script that generates the appxbundle file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an "individual project/app" by setting the `SolutionDir` and building a `.csproj`, all the referenced projects will be built and an `.ipa` created, something like:

```
xbuild 
  /p:SolutionDir="./src" 
  /p:OutputPath="$PWD/artifacts/" 
  /p:IpaPackageDir="$PWD/artifacts/" 
  /p:Configuration=Release 
  /p:Platform=iPhone 
  /target:Build 
  src/iOS/XamarinForms.iOS.csproj
```

Note: This assumes your provisioning profiles are setup on this Mac.

Comment: We converted our xbuild command to use the `SolutionDir` as specified, and then encountered numerous build issues. After fixing all of them (removing NuGet.targets references, resolving NuGet restore issues, and project reference issues) we finally were able to successfully generate a ipa. The only thing that needs to change in your answer is that the `/p:Configuration` and `/p:Platform` need to have values without quotation marks. From what we have seen in the build output is that if you have quotation marks around those values it will create something like this: `""Release"|"iPhone""`